# How can I have optional dependencies which do not produce errors at runtime when they are not installed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependencies

I want to create a package which has various utility features (let's call this the *utility package*) which may or may not be used in a project which implements said package (let's call this these *projects*). The implementation of the utility features come from different packages which need to be installed for a utility feature to work (let's call these *drivers*). These drivers are common to install and should not be installed multiple times (e.g. they should be `peerDependencies`).

I am using NestJS, which is uses `Module` classes to scope dependency injection (plus a lot of other stuff).
Let's say the package exports a module for a GraphQL server and a microservices client. A project using this package could choose to use the GraphQL module only, the microservice client module only, neither, or both. A project **not** using a utility feature means they should not have to install the driver. TypeORM does this for their database driver packages (you only install the driver of the database you actually use).

What I am confused about is how the utility package can work when a driver is not installed by a project. The utility feature is still part of the utility package build, so they are necessary. The most information I have been able to find is to redefine driver types in the utility package, reducing the coupling to the driver packages. While this would work if a driver was only used for its types, but when they have functionality (which is the case here) the driver needs to be imported at some point. I have been digging in the TypeORM github repository and am not much wiser.
How can I make the drivers truly optional?

I am using Node 18 and ESM-style imports.